# Google App Engine Task Queue Backend Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend

I am having trouble running a Backend from a Task Queue in Google app engine. It looks like I have everything set up correctly according to the documentation, but when I try to run the Task the Backend is not started, and I don't get much back from the logs other than a 404 error. It's probably something small that I'm missing but I have been working on it for a couple days now and just can't figure out what it is.

Here is what my Backends.yaml looks like

```
backends:
- name: batchloader
  instances: 1
  options: dynamic
  start: batchcron.app
```

Here is the handler in app.yaml

```
- url: /crons/batch
  script: batchcron.app
  login: admin
```

Here is my taskqueue call to the backend

```
taskqueue.add(url='/crons/batch', target='batchloader')
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you start the backend in the Admin Console? Go to the app engine admin console for your app, on the left you'll see backends, click on that, on that screen you should see your backend listed and click on "start". If you don't see your backend, you need to upload your backend, see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#Commands for help on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update to this issue. It was a couple of small things that I overlooked. Someone1 was right as I did not have the backends started in the admin council. I thought since they were dynamic and would start and stop themselves.So that is fixed now. The other was that in my call to crons/batch I was using the default post method, but the function I was calling was a get. So I just changed that function and everything worked.

Thanks for the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your backends with `appcfg.py backends <dir> update` to create and update your backend.

You can read more about this [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#Commands)